# Unable to install node modules because 'This is related to npm not being able to find a file.'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, npm

So in my recent project I tried to install some node modules, in this case, express and MySQL, which both return the same error:

> npm WARN thecaptain.ga@1.0.0 No repository field.

> npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\projectroot\node_modules\on-finished
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! errno -4058
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\user\projectroot\node_modules\on-
> finished' -> 'C:\Users\user\projectroot\node_modules.on-finished.DELETE'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

I tried to delete all the related files, then reinstalling it, however that did not change anything. I have run `npm init` before the install even attempted to fill in the dependency manually, to then run `npm install`. It happens with every node module in any node project I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was because the dropbox tried to synchronize the files as i was installing the package. Pausing or disabling this fixes the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please:

1 - Ensure no NPM scripts are running.

2 - Navigate to your project route

3 - Run this command:

```
rm package-lock.json && npm i
```

**Note -** it may also be worth trying to delete your 'node_modules' folder in your project directory and running the above command.

Comment: Tells me the && token is invalid (on windows)

Comment: Just run them both separately. Run the RM one first, then npm i after :)

Comment: Ok. Now it worked for both mysql and express, but not for enmap.

Comment: Yes i get the same error as i did before with mysql and express on installation.

Comment: I tried reinstalling node aswell i think my version was outdated. So the already installed enmap module is out of date.